# I have encountered some problems in assigning values to vue data objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a problem with vue assignment.
My code is like this

```
new Vue({
el: "#alarmEchartBar",
data: {
    regusterUrl: Ohttp + "historicalAlarmRecord/chart",
    regDistrictUrl: Ohttp + "district",
    regStreetUrl: Ohttp + "street/",
    regCameraUrl: Ohttp + "camera/",
    meger: false,
    timeUnit: 1,
    startTime: 0,
    endTime: 0,
    districtName: "全部",
    streetName: "全部",
    cameraName: "全部",
    districtData: [],
    streetData: [],
    cameraData: [],
    DID: [],
    SID: [],
    CID: [],
    requestData: {
        "dIds": this.DID,
        "cIds": this.CID,
        "sIds": this.SID,
        "merge": this.meger,
        "timeUnit": this.timeUnit,
        "startTime": this.startTime,
        "endTime": this.endTime,
    },

  }})
```

If you assign this value, requestData is undefined. Isn't it possible to assign this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, it might be good to use computed properties.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html
Please try this code:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#alarmEchartBar",
  data: {
    regusterUrl: Ohttp + "historicalAlarmRecord/chart",
    regDistrictUrl: Ohttp + "district",
    regStreetUrl: Ohttp + "street/",
    regCameraUrl: Ohttp + "camera/",
    meger: false,
    timeUnit: 1,
    startTime: 0,
    endTime: 0,
    districtName: "全部",
    streetName: "全部",
    cameraName: "全部",
    districtData: [],
    streetData: [],
    cameraData: [],
    DID: [],
    SID: [],
    CID: [],
  },
  computed: {
    requestData: function() {
      return {
        "dIds": this.DID,
        "cIds": this.CID,
        "sIds": this.SID,
        "merge": this.meger,
        "timeUnit": this.timeUnit,
        "startTime": this.startTime,
        "endTime": this.endTime,
      },
    }
  }
})
```